# Weka 3.8.6 error cannot load applications

Tags: weka

```
Environment variable 'JAVA_OPTS' does not exist!
Environment variable 'CLASSPATH' does not exist!
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by weka.gui.GUIChooserApp (file:/C:/Program%20Files/Weka-3-8-6/weka.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of weka.gui.GUIChooserApp
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
```

[image: 1]

ar Situation Can Help Me :<
THANKS A LOT

i am getting error using weka version 3.8.6

when i try to use explorer. app loads very slow, almost unresponsive, i

t also almost gives no error, when i try to use console version it just shows warning messages

ANYONE Having Similar Situation Can Help Me :<
THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a different version of Java rather than the one that Weka comes with, to rule out that this is the culprit:

- From [adoptium.net](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/) download a ZIP file (not MSI!) of Java 11 and unzip it somewhere, e.g., on your Desktop (by using the ZIP file you don't have to be admin to make use of it).
- Determine the absolute path to the executable `java.exe` that you just extracted, e.g.:

  ```
  C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\jdk-11.0.18+10\bin\java.exe
  ```
- Determine the absolute path the `weka.jar` of your Weka installation, e.g.:

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8-6\weka.jar
  ```
- Open a Windows command-prompt.
- Run the following command to start up Weka, using the paths that you just determined (use *double quotes* around the paths to account for potential spaces in the paths):

  ```
  "JAVAEXE_PATH" -jar "WEKAJAR_PATH"
  ```

  Which translates to this using the above mentioned paths:

  ```
  "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\jdk-11.0.18+10\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8-6\weka.jar"
  ```

If it is no longer slow, then the Zulu Java that comes with Weka is likely to be the culprit.

If not, you will have to check whether other programs, like an anti-virus, might cause the slowdown.

Comment: first about "does java zulu fail?" i tried using jdk17.0.6 version loaded from homepage itself. and it still causes slowness.
about anti virus, i don't even use windows defender :v

Comment: Try with older version of java, like 8.

Answer (score 0):

i think i found something :v

```
> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @32464a14
        java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.injectClasses(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:792)
        weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.injectAllClassesInFromStream(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:690)
        weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.injectMTJCoreClasses(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:118)
        weka.core.WekaPackageManager.<clinit>(WekaPackageManager.java:255)
        weka.core.ResourceUtils.readProperties(ResourceUtils.java:241)
        weka.core.ResourceUtils.readProperties(ResourceUtils.java:184)
        weka.core.Utils.readProperties(Utils.java:183)
        weka.core.logging.Logger.<clinit>(Logger.java:50)
        weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.main(GUIChooserApp.java:1660)
        java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:306)
        weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)

        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.injectClasses(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:792)
        at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.injectAllClassesInFromStream(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:690)
        at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.injectMTJCoreClasses(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:118)
        at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.<clinit>(WekaPackageManager.java:255)
        at weka.core.ResourceUtils.readProperties(ResourceUtils.java:241)
        at weka.core.ResourceUtils.readProperties(ResourceUtils.java:184)
        at weka.core.Utils.readProperties(Utils.java:183)
        at weka.core.logging.Logger.<clinit>(Logger.java:50)
        at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.main(GUIChooserApp.java:1660)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:306)
        at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by weka.gui.GUIChooserApp (file:/C:/Users/Kenzn2/Downloads/Compressed/stable-3-8/weka/weka.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of weka.gui.GUIChooserApp
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPCLE.png)

Comment: Try with Java 8.

Comment: This is not an answer